# history.listen not working correctly inside React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to be able to call a function every time React recognises the url has changed, but am having trouble with history.listen not firing (the console.log is never printed). I have seen posts saying that this is because I'm using BrowserRouter, but I am getting errors saying "cannot find x inside react-router" whenever I try importing anything from react-router. I currently have react-router and react-router-dom versions 4.1.2

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import './App.css';
import reducers from './common/reducers'
import Routes from './common/Routes';
import RoutesWrapper from './components/RoutesWrapper';
import Login from './Login';

class App extends Component {

    render() {
        const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Login>
                        <div className="App">
                            <div className="widgetCont">
                                <Routes wrapper={RoutesWrapper}/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Login>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
export { Route, Redirect, Link };
```

Routes.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

import { Route } from '../App.js';
import PredictionsCompletedContainer from './containers/PredictionsCompletedContainer';
import GameContainer from './containers/GameContainer';

class Routes extends Component {


    render() {
        const Wrapper = this.props.wrapper;

        const history = createHistory();
        history.listen((location, action) => {
            console.log("inside history listen");
        });

        return (
            <Wrapper>
                <Route exact path="/" component={GameContainer}/>
                <Route path="/predictions-completed" component={PredictionsCompletedContainer}/>
            </Wrapper>
        );
    }
}

export default Routes;
```

Answer (score 1):

With every re-rendering of component, render is getting called.

It causing, listener getting removed as you initialising `history` object.

Its better,put it inside component life cycle `componentDidMount` which going to called only once in life.

```
componentDidMount(){

    const history = createHistory();
        history.listen((location, action) => {
            console.log("inside history listen");
        });
}
```

EDIT :

Its look like,you need to integrate the **[`react-router-redux`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux)**.

Please refer  **[`answer here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48799733/react-router-4-and-props-history-push/48799841#48799841)**.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm still not seeing the console log though unfortunately