# How to navigate to another page in react router v4 in the action

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am building an application that has a login screen and dashboard. When i successfully login i want my app to go to the dashboard but when i call a `history.push('/dashboard');` in my **ACTION**(i think the history push will be called here after a promise). The `URL` changes but does not render the view.

**My Login Component :**

```
onSubmit(values){
    this.props.loginUser(values);
  }
render(){
return(
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
      <Field
        label='Username'
        name='username'
        component={this.renderField}
        type="text"
      />

      <Field
        label='Password'
        name='password'
        component={this.renderField}
        type="password"
      />

      <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
    {this.renderError()}
  </div>
);}}


    function mapStateToProps({profile}){
  return {profile};
}

export default reduxForm({
  validate,
  form:'LoginForm'
})(withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,{loginUser})(Login)))
```

**My Action :**

```
export function loginUser(values){
  return dispatch => axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}verifyuser`,values)
    .then((response)=>{
      if(response.data.code == 'success'){

        dispatch(success(response.data),history.push('/dashboard'));
      }else{
        dispatch(failure(response.data));
      }
    })

    function success(response) { return {type:userConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESS,payload:response}; }
    function failure(response) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_FAILURE, payload:response } }
}
```

**My Dashboard Component :**

```
class Dashboard extends Component {

  render(){
    return(
      <div>Test</div>
    );
  }
}
```

MY routing

```
const App = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
  </Switch>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStore(reducers,applyMiddleware(promise,thunk))}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
  , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN that does not solve my problem sorry

Comment: did you trued `history.push` and react-router?

Comment: Yes i did try it

Comment: Please look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48799733/react-router-4-and-props-history-push/48799841#48799841 Please let me know if still not working

Answer (score 0):

If the url changed, then it means, the history.push has worked, so I guess you have missed to add this route in your `Routes`
Add,

```
<Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard}/>
```

Comment: Hello I have edited my code and added my routing to the question. I am puzzled why it is not rendering

Comment: Ideally, it is supposed to change if you have defined your Route like that and when you are able to change the url using push(), the respective component mentioned in the route should be displayed. Can you create a codesandbox for this. That would be perfect to debug this situation.

Comment: Hi please see this. https://codesandbox.io/s/2ownkp342r